# Building a self-maintaining collection that removes items as they expire?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, collections, concurrency

I am building a system that enables users to enter a phone number to add to their account. The system allows a user to enter the number, that number is then added to my `PendingNumberManager` with a set expiration time. We then dispatch a text message to that number, and wait for the user to enter their verification code in our application. If they enter the correct verification code for their account and number, that number is removed from the `PendingNumberManager` and added to their user account (and persisted to the database).

Overall, the functionality is relatively straightforward until I start factoring in the automatic expiry. Some of the options that jump out to me immediately are:

- Never remove expired entries unless someone tries to fetch them, and then remove the singular expired entry. (Will potentially cause the list to get more and more full over time).
- Check for expired entries on every lookup. (Causes additional overhead on every lookup).
- Have some sort of loop running in another thread that just periodically checks for expired items. (May eat up additional resources when they're not required)

Overall I'm somewhat at a loss on how to handle this the most efficient way. Is there any design pattern or approach that lends itself well to this problem?

---

We currently have a `UserPhoneNumber` table that contains several fields (including a `LastModified` and `Verified field`). In our system, we have multiple different data feeds that can dump data into the `UserPhoneNumber` table. The system currently contains the necessary functionality to add and verify phone numbers, and numbers added by our various data feeds can be manually verified later.

During the registration flow, we want to enable a user to enter and then verify a given number without persisting that number to `UserPhoneNumber` unless it's verified first. If the user abandons the initial account setup/registration prior to verifying their number, they will be forced to go back through that flow again later, so we have no need to persist registration-based unverified numbers.

Comment: Why not just have a separate service that runs a cleanup operation on the database once a day (or hour, or whatever interval you like)? I guess this is like your third option. Not sure what resources it would "eat up", though..?  `DELETE FROM PendingNumbers WHERE ExpirationDate > GETDATE()`

Comment: @RufusL realistically, the numbers are only presently valid for 30 minutes, so it seemed silly for me to have such a shortlived table. There's no reason I couldn't implement a cleanup job, but the overhead seems excessive for such a small use case.

Comment: As for the resource concern, our main platform is already experiencing some out of memory issues that we've been working to fix, we simply didn't want to build something that contributed excess load to the problem.

Comment: I assumed you had a `PendingNumbers` table with something like `UserId`, `PhoneNumber`, `VerificationCode`, and `ExpirationDate`. Where are you storing the numbers if not in a table (if you're storing them in memory, maybe that's part of the issue you're encountering)? What exactly are you trying to clean up? Also, running this server side against a small table would be pretty efficient, wouldn't it? What overhead are you referring to?

Comment: Does it help if you assign a lease to each entry? The lease has a timer. When this timer elapses then you can remove it from the memory queue. Otherwise if the entry is accessed you can release the timer and do your other thing.

Comment: @RufusL currently there's a `UserPhoneNumber` table that includes a `Verified` column. We have multiple data feeds that can place data into this table, and users can manually verify this data later necessary if needed. However, the new registration process requires the number to be verified before it's placed in the `UserPhoneNumber` table. The numbers (and verification codes) are only valid for 30 minutes after they're issued (as the front-end flow is very linear, so realistically they'll verify it in under a minute)

Comment: Ah, presently they're all stored in various database tables and areas. And they all contain various foreign keys. Currently, unverified phone numbers are never removed (nor do we want them to be if they're added by our different data feeds).

Comment: Ok, not sure of a better answer than just running a cleanup service serverside once a day that includes a query that will delete expired records (that were entered by the appropriate data feed). But that's good news that they're not just stored in memory. Good luck!

Comment: @RufusL thanks. The goal was mostly to avoid building any sort of cleanup service on the database side, or to prevent any changes to the database entirely. It looks like I may just have to suck it up and go that route.

Answer (score 2):

This does sound like a "verify Contact data" shema. But the basic principle is also shared by session Systems. You see those all over the internet.

Due to the rather long expriry times involved, this is something I would definitely solve on the DB side - not the programm side. My solution when facing this, was to make a stored Prodedure taht took the ID with two jobs:

1. Delete all timedout stuff
2. Try to check if this number is still in the table

On a success, of course I also remove it from the table.

That way the list will quickly self-clean any failed attempts and you never have a issue that a number stays valid. That little overhead is acceptable, considering this function will only be called 1 to maybe 5 times per registration. This is not a high trafic area of the DB or Programm.

Comment: We have a couple other processes that write unverified data to the user phone numbers table, but in this specific case we don't want to write to the user's table unless the data is verified first. In reality, the phone numbers in the list will only be valid for 30 minutes currently, so there shouldn't be a large amount of overhead.

Comment: @JDDavis Why is a unverified number in the User Data? Just make a extra table "Numers pending verification". `Foreign Key User ID`, `Number`, `expiration time`. Have your verfication code work on that and only update the user Data after verification.

Comment: it's a holdover from our legacy systems. We receive eligibility files that put data into user accounts. Those numbers added through third party processes can be manually verified later. The core registration process simply requires them to enter and verify a number before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

An unverified phone number is a different sort of entity. It has some additional fields not needed for verified phone numbers, e.g. the verification code and the verification code expiration date/time. To maintain a normalized database design, it would go in a different table, e.g. `UserUnverifiedPhoneNumber`, that has different columns.

For operations that require a verified phone number, your application would still interrogate the `UserPhoneNumber` table, which excludes these non-verified phone numbers.

For operations that work with unverified phone numbers (e.g. your registration flow), the application would query the `UserUnverifiedPhoneNumber` table instead. When it does so, it would check the expiration date of any verification code in flight. If it's expired, you have a choice: the application could simply pretend the record doesn't exist, or it could offer a UI for a special case (e.g. "Send me a new verification code").

The final touch would be a recurring service or SQL Agent job that searches the `UserUnverifiedPhoneNumber` table for entries that have been expired more than X days and removes them physically so that the table doesn't just keep growing. You could run this job hourly, daily, or even monthly, depending on your needs.